# Laravel form id (to use Ajax)

Tags: forms, laravel, formbuilder

I've been trying to create a form that will be sent with Ajax in Laravel 5.6, and I need my form to have an id `id='my_super_form'`

I use the laravel-boilerplate and want to use the standard syntax `{{ html()->form()->open() }}`.

However I do it, I get
`<form method='POST' action='url/'>`

I tried: nothing in post, array in open, adding parameters in form(), as simple parameters, as array, whatever I do, I won't get more than action and method. I can't seem to get an id field.

The [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_open) doesn't list the valid parameters, so I'm trying randomly but unless there is a syntax error nothing will work...

Comment: I am not sure but you can try `echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put', 'id' => 'my_super_form'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel-boilerplate uses [spatie html](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-html) to build forms. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-html/v2/introduction).

To add the **id** or **other attributes** to your form, use **attribute()** function:

> {{ html()->form()->attribute('id', 'my_super_form')->open() }}

Comment: Indeed it works, thank you, didn't notice this boilerplate particularity.